# Preparing data for anomaly detection

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, anomaly-detection

I have a task at hand to do anomaly detection on a time series data. I have the code for anomaly detection but am trying to prepare the data for it. The data is shown below.

```
timestampUtc

2016-08-01 14:38:01, 2016-08-01 14:38:06, 2016-08-01 14:38:12, 2016-08-01 14:38:18, 2016-08-01 14:38:22, 2016-08-01 14:38:27, 2016-08-01 14:38:27, 2016-08-01 14:38:30, 2016-08-01 14:38:37, 2016-08-01 14:38:38, 2016-08-01 14:38:38, 2016-08-01 14:38:46, 2016-08-01 14:39:03, 2016-08-01 14:39:03, 2016-08-01 14:39:10, 2016-08-01 14:39:12, 2016-08-01 14:39:15, 2016-08-01 14:39:16, 2016-08-01 14:39:20, 2016-08-01 14:39:28
```

First I would like to make seconds zero in the `timestampUtc` column. Next I would like to create a column that says `count` and would like to count the number of values for that specific minute. For example the output should look like this:

```
timestampUtc count

2016-08-01 14:38:00 12, 2016-08-01 14:39:00 6, 2016-08-01 14:40:00 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.POSIXct()` to transform the string to dates, using some format to ignore seconds, then use `table` to summarize:

```
timestampUtc <- c('2016-08-01 14:38:01', '2016-08-01 14:38:06', '2016-08-01 14:38:12', '2016-08-01 14:38:18', '2016-08-01 14:38:22', '2016-08-01 14:38:27', '2016-08-01 14:38:27', '2016-08-01 14:38:30', '2016-08-01 14:38:37', '2016-08-01 14:38:38', '2016-08-01 14:38:38', '2016-08-01 14:38:46', '2016-08-01 14:39:03', '2016-08-01 14:39:03', '2016-08-01 14:39:10', '2016-08-01 14:39:12', '2016-08-01 14:39:15', '2016-08-01 14:39:16', '2016-08-01 14:39:20', '2016-08-01 14:39:28')
timestampUtc <- as.POSIXct(timestampUtc, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")
table(timestampUtc)
2016-08-01 14:38:00 2016-08-01 14:39:00 
                 12                   8
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your timestamp is already in POSIXt format, and your timestamp data is stored in df-

```
df$count <- 1
df$timestamp <- format(df$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df <- aggregate(count ~ timestamp, data = df, FUN = sum)
names(df) <- c("timestamp", "count")
```

Comment: I think you could have avoided summing a bunch of ones if you just used: `df <- aggregate(count ~ timestamp, data = df, FUN = length)`

Answer (score 1):

Both the `cut` and the `seq` methods for POSIXt classes have an interval option for `breaks` (or `by`) :

```
 timestampUtc <-scan(text="2016-08-01 14:38:01, 2016-08-01 14:38:06, 2016-08-01 14:38:12, 2016-08-01 14:38:18, 2016-08-01 14:38:22, 2016-08-01 14:38:27, 2016-08-01 14:38:27, 2016-08-01 14:38:30, 2016-08-01 14:38:37, 2016-08-01 14:38:38, 2016-08-01 14:38:38, 2016-08-01 14:38:46, 2016-08-01 14:39:03, 2016-08-01 14:39:03, 2016-08-01 14:39:10, 2016-08-01 14:39:12, 2016-08-01 14:39:15, 2016-08-01 14:39:16, 2016-08-01 14:39:20, 2016-08-01 14:39:28",
                      what="", sep=",")
#Read 20 items

table( cut( as.POSIXct(timestampUtc), breaks="min")  )
#------------
2016-08-01 14:38:00 2016-08-01 14:39:00 
                 12                   8
```

Had you wanted 10 or 15 min intervals, it could have been "10 min" or "15 min". One of the other answers so far remove information at the input stage which I see as a questionable practice, but code_is_entropy used `format` with a shortened format string at the stage of passing to `table`.